# propertyMissing of groovy is not working in grails3

Tags: grails, groovy

I have create an abstract class in `src/groovy`

```
abstract class BaseDomain {
    def storage = [:]
    def propertyMissing(String name, value) { storage[name] = value}
    def propertyMissing(String name) { storage[name] }
}
```

I have create the following Domain class

```
class Student extends BaseDomain {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    //....
}
```

But, when I tried to add property on the fly to the student object it is throwing exception, but it supposed to take as it is the nature of groovy as a dynamic programming language

I use Groovy 2.4.10, Grails 3.2.9, IntelliJ

Am I missing any configuration in application.yml, this is the first project i am doing in Grails 3, earlier I worked with Grails 2.5.x, then I had no issues, it worked properly.

Comment: what exception?

Comment: propertyMissingException

Comment: edit the question to include the exception and stacktrace, it's harder to diagnose with so little information provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails 3 makes extensive use of traits to mix in methods, base classes, and interfaces to artifact classes (domain classes, controllers, etc.) and in general the behavior is the same or very similar, but there are some cases like this where the implementation under the hood affects how some things work.

If you use a decompiler or the reflection APIs you can see that your domain classes implement several interfaces which are actually Groovy traits, and the one of interest here is `org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity` because it's the source of an implementation of `def propertyMissing(String name)`. This is there to support multiple datasources, e.g. if there's a second datasource named `"mongo"` then you can make instance method calls using that datasource using the syntax `student.mongo.theMethodName(...)` on an instance that was retrieved from another datasource. Since that method is defined in a trait, the trait method is called and yours is ignored.

The trait could try to call your method, but it's not guaranteed to be there (and in this case not even likely since this isn't a common technique) so that would require a careful implementation.

But you can work around the problem by taking advantage of the logic in Groovy for what to do when there are multiple methods with the same signature from different sources. The method from the last declared trait (in the class declaration via `implements`) is the one that's called. Traits can call `super.methodname(...)` to "chain" calls to other traits that also declare that method.

So change `BaseDomain` from an abstract base class to a trait:

```
package ...

import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

trait DynamicProperties<D> implements GormEntity<D> {

   def dynamic = [:]

   def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
      if (!propertyIsDatasource(name)) {
         dynamic[name] = value
      }
   }

   def propertyMissing(String name) {
      if (propertyIsDatasource(name)) {
         super.propertyMissing(name)
      }
      else {
         dynamic[name]
      }
   }

   boolean propertyIsDatasource(String name) {
      false
   }
}
```

and implement it instead of extending:

```
package ...

class Student implements DynamicProperties<Student> {
   String firstName
   String lastName
}
```

Unfortunately `GormEntity` requires the class name, so you need to redundantly include that in your concrete classes.

Since `DynamicProperties` extends `GormEntity` it will be earlier in the "chain", so it will be called first.

Any domain class that uses more than one datasource will need to override the `propertyIsDatasource` method with custom logic to ensure that datasource names are handled by GORM. Just declare it with the same signature in that domain class. You can remove all of that logic if you know you'll never use multiple datasources in any domain classes.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Thank you very much. feeling very happy to get answered from you. I got so many queries solved by following your posts and learnt a lot. Really happy to get answered. And the explanation is awesome. Its working like a charm